# Поместить несколько значений в буфер обмена

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно поместить в буфер обмена 3 числа(к примеру 244, 3, 6) и потом комбинацией клавиш вывести их (ctrl+v+1 = 244, ctrl+v+2 = 3 и тд).Возможно ли такое сделать ? Насколько я знаю буфер обмена может хранить только одну порцию информации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала записываешь в буфер обмена одно значение с помощью `Clipboard.SetText,` затем считываешь из буфера это значение с помощью `Clipboard.GetText` во временную переменную, и делаешь что-то типа temp=temp+"Какое-то число", опять делаешь `Clipboard.SetText`. Повторять необходимое кол-во раз.

Это решение в лоб, мб кто-нибудь придумает что-нибудь изящнее...

Comment: Это получится, что мы занесем в буфер переменную в которой как бы будет 2 числа ?

Comment: Да. Ты в переменной текстового типа выполняешь свое слияние чисел через какой-нибудь делитель.

Comment: А нельзя через массив это сделать ? Чтобы потом при нажатии на ctrl+v+1 выводить, к примеру, число с индексом 0, то есть 244 и тд?

Comment: Смысл в том, что ты перед записью нового значения в буфер, считываешь все что там находится и плюсуешь к этому значению новое число и опять ложишь назад в буфер.

Comment: Я просто не совсем пойму как потом комбинацией клавиш вывести то, что нужно.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard(v=vs.110).aspx тут все написано. Можно целый Object в буфер поместить=> List<T> точно можно поместить.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое.